# Can't see anything in home directory ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I cannot see any files or folder in my home directory. I believe it is because of nautilus. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the terminal output for the following commmand: `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`? And perhaps cast your eye over this: http://askubuntu.com/q/747398/57576

Comment: @andrew.46
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"

Comment: OIC, I have solved exactly that issue in the post I linked to, the exact answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/747432/57576 . Simply copy and paste the command given there  into a Terminal and all should be fixed after reboot... That probably makes your question a duplicate but I will hold off marking it as such until you have tried the suggested fix, and hopefully fixed your system :)

Comment: @andrew.46 That solution did not work for me. I can see the desktop and all the directories login into nautilus, but not in general settings.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by 'general settings"? And after the attempted fix could you give the results again for `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` which should now be reset to defaults.

Comment: @andrew.46 I can't see anything even after using your solution. I however was able to see something yesterday with nautilus command line option. So I think it is not deleted but somehow hidden. I am not sure what is the issue exactly that keeps everything in my home directory hidden.

Comment: Dot files are hidden by default, is this what you mean? If you press Ctrl + H this will be toggled back into view...

Comment: @andrew.46 Yes those are the hidden files, but I could not see any other files that were there originally.